# Сложности с версткой линий

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть макет header [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 217%;
}

.container {
  background: #070707;
  padding: 5px 0 16px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left_side_block {
  margin: 17px 205px 0 42px;
}

.left_side_block span {
  margin-right: 27px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.left_side_block span:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.right_side_block {
  margin: 12px 42px 0 205px;
}

.left_side_textblock {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.right_side_block span {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left_side_block">
      <div class="left_side_textblock">
        <span>Портфолио</span>
        <span>Блог</span>
        <span>О нас</span>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="logo_block">
      <img src="/img/firstHeaderLogo.svg" alt="Logotype">
    </div>
    <div class="right_side_block">
      <div class="right_side_textblock">
        <span>+7 (495) 120-77-62</span>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Результат: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все так, кроме правой части. Не получается правый текст и линию поставить в нужные положения.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте линии задавать не через `<hr>`, а через нижнюю границу блока.

1. Внутри основного блока флексами разнесите левый, правый блок (будут с линиями) и центральный с логотипом.
2. Задайте левому и правому высоту с половину логотипа (кажется, что линии должны идти по центру общего блока).
3. Внутри левого и правого тоже флексами расположите внутренние элементы.

Вот пример (в html убрал линии и лишние div, классы не менял):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: #070707;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px; /* Внутренние поля контейнера */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left_side_block {
  align-self: start;
  min-width: 33%; /* Ширина блока с горизнтальной линией */
  height: 25px; /* Половина высоты контейнера */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 20px;
}

.right_side_block {
  align-self: start;
  min-width: 33%; /* Ширина блока с горизнтальной линией */
  height: 25px; /* Половина высоты контейнера */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: start;
}

.logo_block {
  min-height: 50px; /* Высота логотипа */
  background-color: tomato;
}



.left_side_block span {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.right_side_block span {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left_side_block">
      <span>Портфолио</span>
      <span>Блог</span>
      <span>О нас</span>
    </div>
   <div class="logo_block">
     <img src="/img/firstHeaderLogo.svg" alt="Logotype">
   </div>
   <div class="right_side_block">
     <span>+7 (495) 120-77-62</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на Вашем месте использовал бы для реализации такой шапки flex:
Идея в том, чтобы убрать тэги `hr` а вместо них нарисовать нижнюю границу `border-bottom` для левого и правого `div`.

Ниже я привел Вам пример кода, который на мой взгляд можно использовать. Там в HTML-документе я добавил обёртку `<div class="header__flex">` для всех элементов, расписал для него стили в css-файле и исправил стили для `.left_side_block` и `.right_side_block`. Только подкорректируйте ширину блоков и нижней линии под свой макет, потому что сложно это сделать, не имея логотипа)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

hr {
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 217%;
}

.container {
    background: #070707;
    padding: 5px 0 16px 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__flex {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.left_side_block {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    flex: 0 1 250px;
}

.left_side_block span {
    margin-right: 27px;

    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;

    color: #ffffff;
}

.left_side_block span:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.right_side_block {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    flex: 0 1 200px;
    text-align: right;
}

.left_side_textblock {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.logo_block {
  text-align: center;
}

.right_side_block span {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__flex">
                <div class="left_side_block">
                    <div class="left_side_textblock">
                        <span>Портфолио</span>
                        <span>Блог</span>
                        <span>О нас</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="logo_block">
                    <img src="/img/firstHeaderLogo.svg" alt="Logotype">
                </div>
                <div class="right_side_block">
                    <div class="right_side_textblock">
                        <span>+7 (495) 120-77-62</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Буду пробовать.